# Highcharts windbarbs tooltip in other unit than m/s

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, suffix

I use Windbarbs in my charts. However, the data for the windbarbs must be in m/s and therefore the tooltips show the same unit.

I want to display the km/h figure and unit in the tooltip. I use the code:

```
thisChart.addSeries({
        name: 'WindBarbs',
        xAxis: 1,
        color: 'black',
        type: 'windbarb',
        visible: true,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true,
            units: [
                ['hour', [3]]
            ]
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y * 3.6}',
            valueSuffix: ' km/h',

        },
        data: WindBarbData
    }, false);
```

However this does not work.
What do I do wrong, how to accomplish this?

NOTE: Windbarbs as tag does not exist. Cannot create it.

Comment: The https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.tooltip (Reference) says:  The HTML of the point's line in the tooltip. Variables are enclosed by curly brackets. Available variables are point.x, point.y, series.name and series.color and other properties on the same form.

However, neither the point.y nor the valueSuffix give a value. For other chart lines this construct works fine.

Comment: Probably this reference link is better: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.windbarb.tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior don't occurs due to `valueSuffix` but because of two mistakes in `tooltip.pointFormat`.

First of all, in `pointFormat` option should be used `point.value` instead of `point.y`.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u5pw83mf/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.windbarb.tooltip.pointFormat

Secondly, multiplication is not possible in the `pointFormat` option. If you need to make some calculations, use `pointFormatter` to achieve that.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0Ljumyan/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Yes, thank you, this works well. Sorry I missed the point.value issue. But now I have an additional question since the number of decimals of the multiplication is about 12 and I want it to be 1 or 2 at most.  Using 'valueDecimals: 1' as an attribute to tooltip does not work.

Comment: OK. I found the answer: I use "(point.value * 3.6).toFixed(1)". I assume this is because it is javascript and not Highcharts in that pointFormatter function